# relating service and controller AngularJS Error: Unknown provider: myservicesProvider <- myservices

Tags: html, angularjs, service, controller

I am getting this error and I tried different methods, but still I have not found any solution.
This is my code:

**app.js**

```
    angular.module('myApp', [ 'myApp.services','myApp.filters', 'myApp.directives',
     'myApp.controllers']).          
     config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/Receive', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial1.html', controller: 'ReceiveCtrl'});
$routeProvider.when('/Pending', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial2.html', controller: 'PendingCtrl'});
 $routeProvider.when('/ResumePending', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial3.html', controller: 'PendingCtrl'});
$routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
 }]);
```

**services.js**

```
    angular.module('myApp.services',[])
    .service('myservice',function($resource)
     {


     var pendings = $resource('myUrl2', {methode: 'GET', isArray:true});
     var items; 

var myPo='rawad al bo3bo3';
var quantity;
var barcode;


   return{
              getItems: function(){

                items =$resource('myUrl', {methode: 'GET', isArray:true});
                return items  ;  
                  },



              setQty: function(qty){
                 quantity=qty;
                 },


 deletePO : function(id){
                },


suspend:function(id){
    //URL needed
},




       }).
      value('version', '0.1');
```

And this is my controllers:

```
  angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).controller('ReceiveCtrl', ['$scope','myservice', function ($scope,myservice) {      


   $scope.po='rawad';
   alert ('WoW!! It is '+myservice.getPO);
 $scope.quantity='';
 $scope.barcode='';



   $scope.addProduct= function(){

    myservice.setQty($scope.quantity);
    myservice.setBc($scope.barcode);
    myservice.addToPliste;

      };

        }]);
```

In the controller I can't access the variable coming from my services... so the alert message won't work and I get this error

> Error: Unknown provider: myservicesProvider <- myservices

Answer (score 4):

Service declaration:

```
angular.module('myApp.services',[]).
    service('myservice',function($resource)
```

Service injection in controller:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
    controller('ReceiveCtrl', ['$scope','myservices', ...
```

The service is named `myservice`, but you use `myservices` when injecting it.

Comment: angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
 .controller('ReceiveCtrl', ['$scope','myservice', function ($scope,myservice) {
          
 
    $scope.po='rawad';
     alert ('WoW!! It is '+myservice.getPO);
     $scope.quantity='';
     $scope.barcode='';
     
   
     
     
       $scope.addProduct= function(){
      
        myservice.setQty($scope.quantity);
        myservice.setBc($scope.barcode);
        myservice.addToPliste;
        
   };
     
     }]);

Comment: Don't post code in comments. Edit your question instead. And never just say "it doesn't work". That's useless. Explain what happens precisely.

Comment: its not accessing the myservice.getPO in the alert here i have the same error...Error: Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource <- myservice

Comment: Okey JB Nizet... i am new to this forum thanks for the advice

Comment: ngResource is a separate module, not bundled with angular.js. It must be added to your JS files and declared in your app's module dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

In your service.js you have named your service as "service" and in your controller you are calling it as "services". That is the error. Change services in controller to service

Try this too;

In your app.js

```
angular.module('myApp', [ 'myApp.services','myApp.filters', 'myApp.directives',
     'myApp.controllers', 'ngResource']).
```

And in your index.html include the `angular-resource.js` file. This might solve your issue.

Comment: Error: Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource <- myservice